# Create aws cloudwatch metrics from ELIXIR code

Tags: elixir, amazon-cloudwatch

I have explored [ExAws.Cloudwatch](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_cloudwatch/ExAws.Cloudwatch.html#content) library. But the documentation was not clear and I had to spend a lot of time to figure out how to push the metrics from Elixir code base.

Answer (score 1):

Your question will probably yield better answers if you properly include things you have tried and what the outcome was, but the following code sample might be helpful:

```
    ExAws.Cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
      [
        [
          dimensions: [
            {"Foo", "Bar"}
            # ... etc
          ],
          metric_name: "Example Thing",
          timestamp: DateTime.utc_now(),
          unit: "Count",
          value: 42
        ]
      ],
      "MyAppNamespace"
    )
    |> ExAws.request()
```

Comment: Great. You can click the checkbox if it works as a solution or upvote it if it is helpful, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Example for `put_metric_data` given in [hex documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_cloudwatch/ExAws.Cloudwatch.html#content) doesn't demonstrate:

1. How to pass multiple dimensions in metric_data.
2. How to use the query response returned by `put_metric_data` method.

Below example will show how to do both.

```
defp publish_api_metrics(status_code, path, client) do
  metric_namespace = "#{client}_api_metrics}"
  metric_name = "api_stats"
  dimensions = %{"status_code": status_code, "api": path, "tenant": client}
  metric_data = [
    [metric_name: metric_name, value: 1.0, dimensions: dimensions]
  ]

  ExAws.Cloudwatch.put_metric_data(metric_data, metric_namespace)
  |> ExAws.request()
end
```

When you execute the above code snippet, metrics called **api_stats** will be created under the defined `{metric_namespace}` with all the dimensions.

Pushed metrics can be found in the AWS console under `metrics` -> `All metrics` search for the `{metric_namespace}` which you pushed using the above code.

OR

Following snippet can be used to fetch the pushed metrics:

```
defp get_api_metrics(client) do
  metric_namespace = "#{client}_api_metrics}"
  ExAws.Cloudwatch.list_metrics(
    [
      namespace: metric_namespace,
      metric_name: "api_stats"
    ]
  )
  |> ExAws.request()

end
```

Hope this helps. #happyCoding

Comment: Why don't you submit a pull request to improve the documentation? https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws_cloudwatch